# How is such a differential equation called?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$ x'(t) = x(t) + x(f(t))$$

Eventually I'd like to find out how such an equation can be solved, but it doesn't have any format I'm familiar with, so don't even know where to start.

Comment: How complicated is $f$? Do you know it?

Comment: Let's assume $f$ is known and linear in $t$.

Comment: Have you tried specific $f$ and coded this? That may help you get started...

Comment: This is a delay-differential equation or something even more general. ODE methods, theoretical and numerical, do not work as they relay on that the values and derivatives of $x$ in the equation are all taken at the same time/argument.

Comment: @DerekOrr what do you mean 'coded' here?

Comment: @bonifaz picking an $f$ and solving the ODE numerically on MatLab, Mathematica, etc.